# Plot PCA using DEseq

Tags: r, pca

I have created this PCA plot using DEseq with my data:

```
boxplotPCA= plotPCA(table, labels =TRUE, isLog= FALSE, main= "PCA")
```

obtaining this plot [image]

But  I would like to make the graph more explanatory by adding dots near each name. 
Someone can help me?